# Can't edit Contact Us form on front page

Tags: plugins, widgets, forms, sidebar, contact

I can edit everything on the homepage except the Contact Us form. It is not a gravity form listed in our list of forms, and it is not a contact form 7 plug in. It is not a sidebar. I cannot get to it in Widgets or any other area. I need help because there is an error on the form and I cannot edit it.

Comment: Can you please share reference URL if you don't mind, so I can review website and help you out.

Comment: www.lumberclub.org        I can edit everything except the form under the Contact Us

Comment: I have checked website and it seems that for is created through custom programming. You fill find in some PHP file of active theme. Search 'contact_form' in your theme folder files using some editor like Notepad++ or Sublime Text.

Comment: I've searched and it is not in my theme folder. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that it's in a plugin - you could try disabling all plugins to see whether that form disappears, and if so, reactivate them one by one until you find out which one it is. It may still be in your theme - have you tried looking through your sidebars and widgets to see whether it may be included as custom html there?

Comment: Try using the plugin String Locator to search for the string contact_form

Answer (score 0):

That contact form is in a widget. Look at the widgets (in Admin area, Themes) to find that widget. (You can tell by inspecting the code for that area, and seeing that the form is contained within a div with a class of 'widget-area', among other classes.)

It's possible that the contact form code is wholly contained in the widget.